# Single Sign On (SSO) via 3rd party ADFS using ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, single-sign-on, adfs

We have a webforms (.net 4.5) application which uses membership for user authentication which we host ourselves. Our clients have Active Directory and ADFS which they host in their own networks, they require our software to use single sign on authenticating against their ADFS server. I'm looking for steps on how to implement this so we can continue to use our normal membership login but use SSO where available.

There's a lot of info out there and I honestly don't know where to start. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up something very similar to this:

[OWIN : ASP.NET MVC application with multiple authentication options](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2016/01/owin-adpnet-mvc-application-with.html)

Basically, use the OWIN Identity stacks to support whatever protocols you want.

Note that this application (RP in ADFS speak) still needs to be configured on the ADFS side.